# Google sheets organizational chart - can't pan or zoom in/out

Tags: google-sheets, charts

[image]

How am I supposed to look through this chart if I can't pan through it or zoom in/out? Am I just supposed to make it big enough on the sheet and then scroll through the sheet?? Seems so stupid.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to do the following:

1. Modify the organizational chart size based on your preference.

   - This will adjust your chart diagram size

> **Customize an organizational chart**
>
> 1. Double-click the chart you want to change.
> 2. At the right, click Customize and then Org.
> 3. hange the size or color of the boxes.

2. Adjust the size of the chart image (make sure that it will show the complete organizational chart that you want to see)
3. To zoom-in/zoom-out, please use the default zoom option in the sheets, example 90% zoom.

Sample:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be you try to move the chart to the second page? On the second page you will have lot of space for zoom in.

**Update:**
you want to get dynamic zoom literally? I'm afraid this is impossible here. Try to consider the option with SaaS-tool with free account like [Zenflowchart](https://www.zenflowchart.com/organizational-chart/),  find solution in [Awesome DataViz](https://github.com/fasouto/awesome-dataviz) or [Awesome BI](https://github.com/thenaturalist/awesome-business-intelligence).

Comment: When I move it to its own sheet, the scroll bar disappears